# Cannot establish SSL connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, letsencrypt

I am trying to establish SSL connection so my users entering the site will not refuse to stay because of insecure HTTP. Basically I am trying to move from HTTP to HTTPS.

I learned many manuals and tutorials, so here quintessence of things what I did:

First I downloaded letsencrypt by:

```
mkdir ~/letsencrypt

cd ~/letsencrypt

git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt

cd letsencrypt

./letsencrypt-auto --help
```

Than I moved to my nginx configuration and corrected it:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/myptoject
server {
    listen 83;
    server_name domainname.tk;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/flaskapp/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

And being in ~/letsencrypt/letsencrypt I run:

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d domainname.tk
```

And after it is going okay, so I entered preffered protocols (both HTTP and HTTPS, my email) but it ended up with message:

```
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for domainname.tk
Using default address 80 for authentication.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. domainname.tk (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authoriza                                            tion :: Invalid response from http://domainname.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/qD7pzA8UtegkcXIhoOQUvCM92eG5hrahtYOLAYJAujw: "<                                            !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <titl"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: domainname.tk
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://domainname.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/qD7pzA8UtegkcXIhoOQUvCM92eG5hrahtYOLAYJAujw:
   "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

   <html>
     <head>
       <titl"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

This error occurs (as far as I now from searching) when there is some conflicts between names, but you can see here that everything is okay with naming. In both cases I have `domainname.tk`.

I am using flask, python, nginx, uwsgi and my working dir (/var/www/flaskapp/) look like:

```
drwxrwxrwx 7 john john      4096 фев 10 19:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 john john      4096 фев  6 21:55 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 john john     61939 янв 26 04:50 certbot-auto
drwxrwxr-x 8 john john      4096 фев 10 11:55 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john       150 фев  9 19:18 home.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       186 фев  8 21:46 myproject.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john       772 фев 10 17:55 myproject.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     12288 фев 10 16:27 .myproject.py.swo
srw-rw---- 1 john www-data     0 фев 10 18:35 myproject.sock
drwxr-xr-x 2 john www-data  4096 фев 10 17:55 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john       104 фев  9 18:18 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john      4096 фев  9 19:18 templates
drwxrwxrwx 5 john john      4096 фев  8 21:44 venv
drwxrwxr-x 3 john john      4096 фев 10 19:58 .well-known
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        68 фев  8 21:45 wsgi.py
```

I created .well-known/acme-challenge directory manually..

So I can't figure out what is wrong here.. It looks like perfectly working case but I am getting an error trying to establish SSL keys.. 
Can anyone help..?

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT ONE**

I should add, what happens when I go to `http://domainname.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/qD7pzA8UtegkcXIhoOQUvCM92eG5hrahtYOLAYJAujw`

I see my home page and nothing else..
html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>domainname.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="domainname.tk">
    <meta name="keywords" content="domainname.tk">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23441223-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://myipaddress:83/" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the relevant distribution?

Comment: What happens when you browse to `http://domainname.tk/.well-known/acme-challenge/qD7pzA8UtegkcXIhoOQUvCM92eG5hrahtYOLAYJAujw` with a web browser?

Comment: I recommending using the steps for let´s encrypt in Ubuntu https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 ; the default hhtps port is 443 and not 83.

Comment: Thank you! Of course I read that before.. honestly my site is running on port 83 and changing it to 443 would probably crush the whole site

Comment: My understanding (I don't use Lets Encrypt, so I may well be wrong) is that the http verification needs the standard ports in order to work.  DNS verification should work regardless of which port you use on your server.